# So when I come to London my English will be better vs so when I'll come to London my English will be better

Tags: verbs

> "So when I come to London my English will be better" vs
>
> "So when I'll come to London my English will be better"

Can anyone help me with these phrases?

Thanks

Comment: First one is correct because "I'll" is short for "I will". "When" already indicates that you'll come in the future, so you don't tell the reader you'll will come.

Comment: The second is ungrammatical for most speakers.

Comment: The present tense is often used (with a temporal phrase) to specify future events: 'I fly to London tomorrow.' 'The tournament begins on Thursday.' 'I'm back next Tuesday.' // Constructions using modal 'will' are not used in prepositional phrases used as temporal adverbials (*'When I will get there, I'll have dinner') though they are with temporal pseudo-subjects ('When I will get there is anyone's guess').

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of English that gives problems to many learners.

We never use an explicit future tense in a "when" or "if" clause.

So "When I come to London", not "When I will/I'll come to London".

There are a few exceptions, but they're rather special. For normal purposes, you can take that as a rule.

Comment: So would it be correct if I used the phrase ' when I come to London my English will be better?'

Comment: A good way to think about it is you're thinking of yourself in that specific moment in the future - the "when" moment.  At that point, getting there happens in the present, hence the present tense.

Comment: The trouble with that argument, @JimMacKenzie, is that it only works in the future: if you accept it, why don't we say "When I am going to work, I saw John"? For that reason, I don't think it's helpful.

Answer (score -2):

"When I come to London..." is not 'present simple', it is describing (now) an uncertain possibility (subjunctive mode).  What we can say is that I haven't come to London, and I'm not sure when/if I ever will.  But in the event I DO come to London then my English will improve.

Comment: There's nothing "subjunctive" about "When I come to London". It's not an _irrealis_ (like "if I come to London") and would not have been expressed by a subjunctive verb at any stage of the language. The verb is indeed present simple; but as in many cases in English, this can be used with future meaning, and in this syntactic context an explicit future is not allowed. -1 for misinformation.

Comment: @ColinFine - as you say, a usage that gives problems to many learners... :-)